# How to open html hyperlink from Chrome / Edge to IE?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, vb.net

How to open link from Chrome / Edge to IE only?

I know about security issue but my higher ups still wants to do this and its not up to me. All our website stored inside a local data warehouse in office and our website/applications doesn't show up on google. Only staff have local access to these applications

I want to open following folder using HTML or VB.NET or js

```
Server/Public/websiteFoldeer/Document
```

`Google Chrome` blocks this feature so my work around was to simple re-direct link to `IE` web browser which doesnt block this feature

```
<a href="file://Server/Public/websiteFoldeer/Document"/>
```

now for some reason above link is opening in `Microsoft Edge`, which does block this feature

if there is a better work around please let me know.

Comment: Looks like you have to run with shortcut : https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags?force_isolation=true

Comment: do you know if there is a way without setting?

Answer (score 0):

As you will no doubt hear, this is a very bad idea. With that said, as you discovered, the url is opening with the default web browser. If you need it to open in Internet Explorer, you'll have to call the "iexplore.exe" and pass the url as a parameter.

You will have to use something like:
<a href="javascript:exec('C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe', "file://Server/Public/websiteFoldeer/Document");"/>